# Comma to be considered in regex expression

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a variable with values like

```
 l_buffer := '10223,1600003B,Admin Officer,00000004,"Org Land, Inc.",ORGA03,ORGA03 HR & Admin'
```

Now I am using while condinition to check the comma delimeted columns. But in that case it is considering `"Org Land, Inc."` as two columns

Org Land and Inc. But because it is enclosed with double quotes it should be considered as one. Is there a way regex can solve this issue ?

Comment: Use [`[^,]+|"[^"]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/wO3rC6/1).

Comment: You asked this question already, just one day ago, why open it again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma-delimited fields in a csv file in plsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502875/comma-delimited-fields-in-a-csv-file-in-plsql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to split a CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv)

Answer (score 0):

See also an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144431/regex-to-split-a-csv/18147076?s=1|1.7658#18147076) I made about this same problem:

- divide your sample text on the comma delimits
- will process empty values
- will ignore double quoted commas, providing double quotes are not nested
- trims the delimiting comma from the returned value
- trims surrounding quotes from the returned value

**The Regex**

```
 (?:^|,)(?=[^"]|(")?)"?((?(1)[^"]*|[^,"]*))"?(?=,|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Example**

https://regex101.com/r/qR9nC2/1

**Sample Text**

> 10223,1600003B,Admin Officer,00000004,"Org Land, Inc.",ORGA03,ORGA03 HR & Admin

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  ``
2.  [0-5]   `10223`
MATCH 2
1.  ``
2.  [6-14]  `1600003B`
MATCH 3
1.  ``
2.  [15-28] `Admin Officer`
MATCH 4
1.  ``
2.  [29-37] `00000004`
MATCH 5
1.  [38-39] `"`
2.  [39-53] `Org Land, Inc.`
MATCH 6
1.  ``
2.  [55-61] `ORGA03`
MATCH 7
1.  ``
2.  [62-79] `ORGA03 HR & Admin`
```